# Is there a way to restore deleted photos from a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-photos

Another admin on a Facebook page deleted some photos by mistake. Is there a way to restore them? the actions do not even appear on the page's activity log..

I know that you can restore photos and messages of your account using the "Download all my data" feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXrRiKkMrjo

But I cannot find a way to do the same for my Facebook page's photos..

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to restore a deleted photo from a Facebook page. Once it's deleted, it's gone.

https://www.facebook.com/help/208547132518386